# Policy for Cake\ORM\Entity has not been defined

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization

Im following along the CMS tutorial in cakephp:

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authorization.html

I've followed along step by step and have gotten to authorization step and keep getting the same errors:
**Policy for Cake\ORM\Entity has not been defined.** if i try to edit, add or delete an article

**The request to /users did not apply any authorization checks.** if I go to users

the article policy look like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Policy;

use App\Model\Entity\Article;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;

class ArticlePolicy
{
    public function canAdd(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        // All logged in users can create articles.
        return true;
    }

    public function canEdit(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        // logged in users can edit their own articles.
        return $this->isAuthor($user, $article);
    }

    public function canDelete(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        // logged in users can delete their own articles.
        return $this->isAuthor($user, $article);
    }

    protected function isAuthor(IdentityInterface $user, Article $article)
    {
        return $article->user_id === $user->getIdentifier();
    }
}
```

The articlesController looks like:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php

namespace App\Controller;
//appcontroller is the main php controller  
class ArticlesController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize(): void
    {
        //initialise is used normally to load components you wish to use across different methods
        //e.g if you wanted to use the paginator component in multiple functions you would load in the initialize
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        //loads flash messages
        // loaded in the appController $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        //fetches all the articles
        //goes into the database and finds all the articles
        $articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Articles->find());
        //this method passes variables into the view file
        //this 'articles' relates to the foreach loop in templates/articles/index.php line 12
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }

    public function view($slug = null)
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
       // Update retrieving tags with contain()
       $article = $this->Articles
        ->findBySlug($slug)
        ->contain('Tags')
        ->firstOrFail();
    $this->set(compact('article'));
    }
    //in order to view this we need to create a view for it
    //the view we have created for it are located in src/templates/add.php
    //To view in the browser use url: http://localhost/cms/articles/add
    public function add()
    {
        $article = $this->Articles->newEmptyEntity();
        $this->Authorization->authorize($article);
    
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
    
            // Changed: Set the user_id from the current user.
            $article->user_id = $this->request->getAttribute('identity')->getIdentifier();
    
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
        }
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();
        $this->set(compact('article', 'tags'));
    }

    public function edit($slug)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles
            ->findBySlug($slug)
            ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
            ->firstOrFail();
        $this->Authorization->authorize($article);
    
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData(), [
                // Added: Disable modification of user_id.
                'accessibleFields' => ['user_id' => false]
            ]);
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list')->all();
        $this->set(compact('article', 'tags'));
    }

       //deletes the article specified by $slug
       public function delete($slug)
       {
     
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

        $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        $this->Authorization->authorize($article);

           if ($this->Articles->delete($article)) {
               $this->Flash->success(__('The {0} article has been deleted.', $article->title));
               return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
           }
       }

       public function tags()
       {
            $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
           // The 'pass' key is provided by CakePHP and contains all
           // the passed URL path segments in the request.
           $tags = $this->request->getParam('pass');
       
           // Use the ArticlesTable to find tagged articles.
           $articles = $this->Articles->find('tagged', [
                   'tags' => $tags
               ])
               ->all();
       
           // Pass variables into the view template context.
           $this->set([
               'articles' => $articles,
               'tags' => $tags
           ]);
       }
}
```

usersController looks like below

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\User[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Articles'],
        ]);

        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        $user = $this->Users->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => [],
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        // Configure the login action to not require authentication, preventing
        // the infinite redirect loop issue
        $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['login', 'add']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            // redirect to /articles after login success
            $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
                'controller' => 'Articles',
                'action' => 'index',
            ]);

            return $this->redirect($redirect);
        }
        // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
        if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $this->Authentication->logout();
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody see why the authorization isn't working on edit, add, delete and why I can't access the users?

Comment: The problem with accessing users is just as it says: you haven't applied any authorization check in those functions. You need to either call `skipAuthorization` like you did in `login`, or `authorize` like you did in the articles `add` function.

Comment: For adding the article, the error message sounds like you've got a generic entity object there, not an actual Article. Check the type of `$article` when you make that `authorize` call.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have this problem, I am getting a generic entity instead of (in my case) a Property object.  What might be causing this?

Comment: @bemoore, it's generally because you've read the entity using a generic table class instead of the correct one. That can be due to table class naming, capitalization, etc.